Multilist field data not appearing in Sitecore rendering props
I'm trying to figure out a multilist field on a rendering in Sitecore 10.2 headless. I created a rendering in Sitecore. It has the Datasource Resolver. The datasource has a single field, 'locations', which is a Multilist field, and the rendering uses the Datasource Resolver. I have it on a page, and when I check the page in the rendering api (sitecore/api/layout/render?item=/testing/...) it shows the data I expect: "fields":{"locations":[...]}. But I can't get the data in my app, I'm not getting locations in the data at all.
In getStaticProps, when I inspect the _rendering object, it looks like this, with no 'locations':
fields: {
    items: []
}

It's the same when I inspect the props passed into the rendering - the props only have 'items' under 'fields', no locations. These are the props I made:
export type PromoLocationCardListingProps = TestProps &
  ComponentWithContextProps & {
    fields: {
      locations: LocationPage[];
    };
};

type LocationPage = LocationPageHeaderPageProps & {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  name: string;
  displayName: string;
};




The answer is silly, but it turns out my base template wasn't published to Edge. It's helpful though to remember that /sitecore/api/layout/render uses the Sitecore database, NOT edge - so it can give you a preview of the data structure, but does not mean that the templates or items are published to Edge
